# How can I estimate the exponent of the Floating Point Arithmetic representation of a decimal number?

Tags: numerical-methods, floating-point

I am dealing with sums and substractions of large and small numbers in Matlab and I would like to estimate the exponent $e$ of the representation of the number in the computer which is in the form

$x = (-1)^{s} 2^e \ 1.f,$

in order to estimate the rounding error commited while storing it without having to manually pass it to binary representation.

Comment: Do you mean the biased exponent of the floating point number or simply $\log_2|x|?$

Comment: The biased exponent.

Comment: That depends on the floating pint precision. Add $1023$ for double and $127$ for single, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponent_bias

Comment: Do al 64 bit computer use then the same precision on every program?

Comment: Use `log2`, see https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/log2.html. It will return the exponent one larger than you want, since it supposes the mantissa to be `0.1f` instead of `1.f`.

Comment: @LutzL As far as I infer, `log2(x)` returns exactly $log_2(x)$

Comment: Read again the friendly manual: `[F,E] = log2(X)`: For real X, F satisfies the equation: `X = F.*2.^E`.  `E` is integer, `F` real, usually in the range `0.5 <= abs(F) < 1`.

Answer (score 0):

Excerpt of facts from https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/log2.html

```
[F,E] = log2(X)
```

returns a pair of real and integer number (or arrays of it if `X` is an array)

For real `X`, the pair `E,F` satisfies the equation `X = F.*2.^E`.  `E` is integer, `F` real, usually in the range `0.5 <= abs(F) < 1`.

This function corresponds to the ANSI® C function `frexp()` and the IEEE floating-point standard function `logb()`.

---

Note however that as `(1.ddd)_2 = 2 * (0.1ddd)_2`, the result you are looking for is `E-1`. (Which may be irrelevant, as you want to compare sizes.)